# assign values to the reference return type directly in c++

Tags: c++

I am new to c++ programming, and I wonder how `add(c1, c2).getVal()` works.

Below is my code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Cents {
    int m_val;

public:
    Cents(int val_in) : m_val(val_in) {};

    int getVal() const {
        return m_val;
    }
};

Cents add(const Cents& c1, const Cents& c2){
    return Cents(c1.getVal() + c2.getVal());
}

int main(){
    Cents c1(10);
    Cents c2(10);
    int val = add(c1,c2).getVal();
    cout << val << endl;
}
```

As we can expect, `add(c1,c2)` creates Cents instance and returns it.

So I thought that we have to save that returned instance somewhere for later usage.

I thought below code would be okay.

```
Cents returnedInstance = add(c1,c2);

returnedInstance.getVal();
```

But how can `int val = add(c1,c2).getVal();` works since we didn't save returned instance of add(c1,c2) somewhere?

How can we directly call `getVal()` method to `add(c1,c2)`?

Comment: It's just how the language works. `getVal()` returns a temporary object that you can access without saving it anywhere.

Comment: it is similar to , how 2+3*5 executes.

Comment: It's on the stack (though that's an implementation detail, not something that the language standard dictates).

Comment: You do not need to save your values in variables unless you want it for some value evaluation. Basically you could also write `cout << add(c1,c2).getVal() << endl;`

Comment: A temporary `Cents` is created to hold the returned object, and `getVal()` is called on that temporary.    So `int val = add(c1,c2).getVal();` is notionally equivalent to something like `int val;  {Cents temp = add(c1,c2); val = temp.getVal();}`  so that `temp` does not exist in later code (and your cannot access it directly at all).   The compiler may do other things too (e.g. store the temporary in a register) - but, whatever it does, you don't get to see the details unless you peer at machine code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works the same as printing (2 + 3) without using a variable.
When you call add(c1, c2) a temporary Cents object is returned. It doesn't matter if you save it on a variable or not. As long as it is a Cents object you can use add method on it.